# Turn a text on y axis

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a project for school, and I have to make a little game. But I have a problem :'(
I would like to create a code (not an animation) to make turning a text on y axis. My code is at the end of the post
It's turn perfectly **BUT** when the animation is ended, the text inversed :(
Is there any solution ?
Too, when the rotation on the y axis is egal to 90, I would like to change the text. I know how to do it but that just a precision :p

```
transform.GetChild(0).transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.GetChild(0).transform.rotation, new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0), 0.01f);
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please show screenshot of the "inversed"  text. *"egal to 90"*  What is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hellium for your help but I found the solution for my question ! (Maybe if you have some time, try to optimize this code, I'm not a pro with Unity :/)

```
Quaternion fromRotation = transform.GetChild(0).rotation;
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
        child.rotation = rotation;
        if (child.GetComponent<Text>().text == name && child.rotation.y < -0.6)
        {
            child.localScale = new Vector3(-1, child.localScale.y, child.localScale.z);
            child.GetComponent<Text>().text = "1";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses [Quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html) to represent rotation, and should be handled with **care**.

I advise you to use `Quaternion.Euler` which takes simple angles as parameters.

```
public float rotationSpeed = 0.01f ;
private Transform child;
private float initialYRotation;
private bool textChanged = false;

private void Awake()
{
    child = transform.GetChild(0);
    initialYRotation = child.rotation.eulerAngles.y ;
}

private void Update()
{
    Quaternion fromRotation = child.rotation ;
    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler( 0, 180, 0 ) ; // Not the same as new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0) !!!
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Lerp( fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed );
    child.rotation = rotation;
    if( !textChanged && Mathf.Abs( child.rotation.eulerAngles.y - initialYRotation ) > 90 )
    {
        // Change the text
        textChanged = true ;
    }
}
```

---

If you want your object to make a complete rotation of 360°. Quaternions are not ideal, I think you can use `Vector3` without any problem:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 0.01f ;
private Transform child;
private float initialYRotation;
private bool textChanged = false;

private void Awake()
{
    child = transform.GetChild(0);
    initialYRotation = child.rotation.eulerAngles.y ;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 fromRotation = child.eulerAngles ;
    Vector3 toRotation = new Vector3( 0, 360, 0 ) ;
    Vector3 rotation = Vector3.Lerp( fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed );
    child.eulerAngles = rotation;
    if( !textChanged && Mathf.Abs( rotation.y - initialYRotation ) > 90 )
    {
        transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = "Success";
        textChanged = true ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I just made some changes to your code (https://pastebin.com/H1dMyws8), but I have a problem ! The text is again inversed... The text change, but the 1 isn't in the good orientation (facing right insted of left >.<)

Comment: Again, **be careful** you are using the `y` component of the **quaternion**, instead of the **eulerAngles**. Moreover, you should consider the optimizations I've suggested if you want to improve your skill.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! But it doesn't resolve my problem :/

Comment: Simply because the final rotation flip the gameobject (rotation of 180°). Do you want to rotate the gameobject by 360°?